# Running case together is failing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, spring-boot, junit

I have developed an email service using Spring Boot App. My project structure looks like:
MailServiceProject -> src -> main ,test
test ->java -> org.company.junit -> A, B, C, D

When I run my test case individually from A,B,C or D folder they ran fine.. But if I ran all the test cases from org.company.junit package, some of my test cases always fail. I notice the pattern that the test cases which actually send email out fails. And throws:
 java.lang.Exception: GeneralException

Is there any way to get more detailed error or any idea why this behave so weirdly.

TIA.

Comment: Can you share your code, so we can reproduce?

Comment: Thanks you cheffee for your response, your comment when unnoticed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was one file which was creating the issue. Apparently, we are using Jmockit  to mock some method to throw specific exception, once the class exists mock up still exists and it throws exception for the following test cases.